# Accuracy and Validation Accuracy stay unchanged while both losses reduce. Tried everything I could find, still doesn't work

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

So, I am trying to code a multivariate LSTM for time series forecasting, and in my model, the losses decrease but accuracy metrics do not change at all. I tried changing number of neurons, layers, learning rate, early stopping, activation function on the output layer, and l2 regularization but nothing works. I am a beginner in machine learning, and so any help would be appreciated.Most of my efforts were like throwing stones in the dark. I am attaching a the GitHub link to my code, as well as a few of the training epochs.

```
# Importing the Keras libraries and packages
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.regularizers import l2
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64,activation='sigmoid',return_sequences=True,input_shape = (trainX.shape[1],trainX.shape[2])))
model.add(LSTM(32,activation='sigmoid',return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(trainY.shape[1]))
opt = Adam(learning_rate= 1e-3)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss = 'mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

```
Model: "sequential_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_6 (LSTM)                (None, 200, 64)           19200     
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_7 (LSTM)                (None, 32)                12416     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 32)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 33        
=================================================================
Total params: 31,649
Trainable params: 31,649
Non-trainable params: 0
```

```
es_callback = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3)
history = model.fit(trainX,trainY,epochs=40,batch_size= 32,verbose=1,validation_split=0.2, callbacks= [es_callback])
```

```
Epoch 1/40
214/214 [==============================] - 58s 169ms/step - loss: 0.1663 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.0483 - val_accuracy: 5.8617e-04
Epoch 2/40
214/214 [==============================] - 35s 164ms/step - loss: 0.0497 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.0446 - val_accuracy: 5.8617e-04
Epoch 3/40
214/214 [==============================] - 35s 164ms/step - loss: 0.0309 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.0092 - val_accuracy: 5.8617e-04
Epoch 4/40
214/214 [==============================] - 35s 163ms/step - loss: 0.0143 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.0230 - val_accuracy: 5.8617e-04
Epoch 5/40
214/214 [==============================] - 35s 163ms/step - loss: 0.0115 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.0160 - val_accuracy: 5.8617e-04
Epoch 6/40
214/214 [==============================] - 35s 163ms/step - loss: 0.0099 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.0172 - val_accuracy: 5.8617e-04
```

My code: https://github.com/RiddhimanRaut/Deep-Learning-based-CPR-estimation/blob/main/CPR_prediction_multivariate_LSTM_tobetrialled_1.ipynb

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using accuracy? Accuracy is a classification metric and you have a regression problem.

Comment: Ahh. Okay. How do you decide if a regression problem is accurate? I didn't include accuracy in the beginning, but while the losses converge well, it does poorly in future prediction cases. So I felt maybe accuracy was the problem. Training losses drop smoothly, and while validation loss graph might have a few peaks, it too does drop to around 0.0007. A model is supposed to overfit when validation losses increase after a certain time, and that is certainly not the case here, it converges to a low value. I'm not sure what to do now.

Comment: That is a different problem, and "poorly in future prediction" does not really say anything, that your model does not work as you would like is not a programming problem.

Comment: What do you do, in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Accuracy is the metric for classification tasks. To measure if a regression model is good or not, measurement such as MSE can be applied.
I think the discussion [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142873/how-to-determine-the-accuracy-of-regression-which-measure-should-be-used) can provide more information.

Comment: I did use mse as my loss function, and both of them converge to very low values. Why then, does it behave badly in prediction?